# Using images as map markers in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps, markers

I'm developing a flood alerts mobile application, which has a map in it. I'm pulling data from a JSON, one piece of the data is a severity level of the floods. There are three levels with symbols corresponding to each. Currently i'm using place holder default markers (circles coloured corresponding to the level) but I'd like to be able to set the symbols in their place.

I've looked everywhere and any solution is either over my head or just not suitable. Any ideas?

P.S. the map should end up like [this one](http://apps.environment-agency.gov.uk/flood/142151.aspx) (I'm using the same data)

Answer (score 0):

Create a MapOverlay element and set it's content to an image object. You can use negative margins on the image to get it to align the image pin point to the coordinate. http://mendez.quora.com/Working-with-Pushpins-and-Maps-in-Windows-Phone-8

Alternatively you can use the Windows Phone toolkit which provides a Pushpin class and modify it's template as needed: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/maps-in-windows-phone-8-and-phone-toolkit-a-winning-team-part-1/